# using colorramp and Object info random and join the objects

Tags: materials

I have a leaf object I used a colorramp with Object info random connected to the colorramp..  When I duplicate the leaf, it creates a leaf with different color...   After creating several leaves,
I tried to join them, but when I do, it changes the leafs all to the same color..  How do you join them and maintain the different colors...
I was using a tutorial and maybe he skipped a step but when I join the leaves to the tree,
all the leaves end up with the same color

thanks

Comment: Perhaps the tutorial parents the leaves to the trees rather than joining them.  Select the leaves, select the tree and type CTRL-P to join.

Comment: The tutorial stated to do ctrl+J   to join them.

Comment: Then you may want to add your blend file to your question ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) and maybe also a pointer to that part of the tutorial, if it's available and not paid.  If it's paid you might want to ask on their help forum.

Comment: I cannot get the file to upload.. I put the file in the box but see no where to upload it to you

Comment: You have to check the two boxes indicating you know the ToS and you have to add the URL of your question in the URL box.  You can get the URL by clicking 'share' on the question and copying the URL it gives you.

Comment: I checked the only two boxes on the screen ... dropped my file into the box where it goes, pasted this page link and typed the information about the tutorial I used  and clicked "Upload"    it doesn't look like it goes anywhere.. takes me to another screen that has a download button ...  n the tutorial "Create a Beautiful Fall Road - Blender Tutorial - 01 Terraine and trees" by CG Geek, he eventually converts the particle system & deletes it.. then he joins all the leaves to the tree at which time leaves end up same color

Comment: That other screen has a block of text with an 'img' in it.  copy that block of text, edit your question, and paste the block of text.  That'll add to your question the details we would need to get your blend file.  But you've answered your own question "joins all the leaves...leaves end up the same color".  You can't retain the random _Object_ color if you join the leaves because they're now all one object

Comment: Okay..  if it can't be done, that's what I needed to know....

Comment: It can't be done that way.  It can be done by replacing the Object Info Node in your shader with a Geometry Node and using the 'Random Per Island' output, in your case.  You added enough info in your comment to @syborg64 answer to give me the info I wanted your blend file for.

Comment: He didn't skip a step in the tutorial. Note that there is no more rendered view of the trees after joining them with the leaves in his tutorial. In part 2 of the tutorial, where he's creating trees all over again for whatever reason he's doing the same thing, joining with Ctrl+J, and in the comments there someone is asking the exact same thing as you did here, and Steve that it's normal that they al have one color, but the random factor still affects duplicate trees, i.e. the trees will vary in color from one object to another. It's just not good for a tutorial to never mention that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You may instead want to use Input -> Geometry -> Random per island.
If your leaves each only have one UV island

[image]

Comment: I'll try that... I tried to upload the file but no luck.. see no way to do it...

Comment: I have no idea is it has their own uv island...  I used an image of a leaf as a image plane, then we added some nodes to it along with the Colorramp and the Object Info Random and if you duplicate the leaves alone, they do change color each duplicate..  once the particle system puts the leaves on the tree, there are multiple colored leaves on the tree.. in the tutorial  "Create a Beautiful Fall Road - Blender Tutorial - 01 Terraine and trees" by CG Geek,  he eventually converts the particle system & deletes it.. then he joins all the leaves to the tree at which time leaves end up same color

Comment: @BKaur What exactly didn't work uploading the file? As Marty commented above, the screen following the upload shows **Share this file: Add this text to your post** and then some html code which you have to insert in your question. Not that it's necessary here, but I guess you might be asked to add a file again in future questions.